# JPA oredered lists @OrderedBy and @OrederColumn

Tags: jpa, orm

I have a question about the @OrderBy and @OrderColumn of the JPA spec.

The problem is that I will have an entity that maintains a list of elemets. Each element will appear in several lists. As I understand the @OrderBy and @OrderColumn annotations, you cannot have the same element appear in different positions in many ordered lists. I just can't believe this.

Can someone explain these annotations a bit? The difference between these two annotations? Specifically how I could do soemthing like this:

```
@Entity
public class Class{

@ManyToMany
private List<Students> studentsInRankedOrder;
// this list should be ordered by class rank.
// but a student who is ranked 1 in one class will most likely not be ranked 1
// in another course. 

}

@Entity
public class Student{

@ManyToMany
private List<Class> enrolledIn;

}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.1.1/apache-openjpa/docs/manual.html#ref_guide_mapping_jpa_coll_order

I understand now. "Order columns are always in the container table." This makes much more sense to me.